# org.hibernate.HibernateException: load is not valid without active transaction

Tags: hibernate, spring, aspectj, spring-transactions, spring-annotations

I am getting the following error while load a user data.

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: load is not valid without active transaction
```

**I am using AspectJ compile time weaving and spring 3.O. and Hibernate 3.0**

Below is my code and configuration file.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT)
public boolean add(User user) {
  getUser(user)
}

public User getUser(User user) {
    Session session = this.getSession();
    User user = ( User ) session.load(User.class, 130);
    return user;
}
```

Configuration:

```
<bean id="hbSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Initializes Transaction manager to handle hibernate transactions -->
<bean id="hbTxManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hbSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="hbTxManager"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Still a question? If yes, I would like to see your class header and also would like to see how you are calling the failing `getUser(...)` and `add(..)` method. Maybe you do have a full stacktrace.